# change the position of a line in a file using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I would like to know how to change the position of a line in a file (preferably using sed). For example, consider the file that contains

```
goal identifier statement  
let statement 1  
let statement 2  
forall statement  
other statements
```

I would like to be able to do this

```
goal identifier statement  
forall statement  
let statement 1  
let statement 2  
other statements
```

where I change the position of the **forall** line and bring it after the **goal** line. **forall** and **goal** are regexps that can be used to identify the lines.

Comment: This is an interesting problem. To make it a good question on StackOverflow, please add the code you've tried to use to achieve a solution. Check out the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) pages for some guidelines on what makes a good question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can try, for move `line 4` to `line 2`, I want to move `line A` to `line B`, where `A>B`

```
sed -n '2{h; :a; n; 4{p;x;bb}; H; ba}; :b; p' file
```

or `A<B`

```
sed -n '2{h; d}; 4{p; x;}; p' file
```

you get, in first case: move `line 4` to `line 2`

```
goal identifier statement
forall statement
let statement 1
let statement 2
other statements
```

you get, in second case: move `line 2` to `line 4`

```
goal identifier statement  
let statement 2  
forall statement  
let statement 1  
other statements
```

**Explanation**

```
sed -n '              #silent option ON
    2{                #if is line 2
        h             #Replace the contents of the hold space with the contents of the pattern space
        :a            #label "a"
        n             #fetch the next line
        4{            #if is line 4
            p         #print line 4
            x         #Exchange the contents of the hold and pattern spaces
            bb        #goto "b"
        }
        H             #appends line from the pattern space to the hold space, with a newline before it.
        ba            #goto "a"
    }
    :b                #Label "b"
    p                 #print
' file
```

**EDIT**

If You want use `regex` for identify the lines, you can modify first command

```
sed -n '/goal/{p;n;h;:a;n;/forall/{p;x;bb};H;ba};:b;p' file
```

Comment: I think they want to move lines based on regexp match not position?

Comment: @123 It's true, I misunderstood, I'm going to modify

Comment: Nice could use a single branch though using something like `sed -n '/goal/{p;:1;n;/forall/!{H;b1};p;x;D};p'`

Comment: @Jose The regex (2nd command) works like a charm. Could you add the explanation for the regex command as well ?

Comment: @123 Works as well. Kindly explain the 'single branch' concept though.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat r.awk
BEGIN {
    forall_re = "^forall" # examples of regexps
    goal_re   = "^goal"
}

function tag(l) { # tag a line
    if      (l ~ goal_re  ) return "goal"
    else if (l ~ forall_re) return "forall"
    else                    return "rest"
}

{ # store entire file in array; give a tag to every line
    lines[NR] = $0 
    tags[NR]  = tag($0)
}

function swap0(a, i, j,   tmp) {
    tmp = a[i]; a[i] = a[j]; a[j] = tmp
}

function swap(i, j) {
    swap0(lines, i, j); swap0(tags, i, j)
}

function rise(i) {
    # TODO: add error check
    while (i - 1 > 0 && tags[i - 1] != "goal") {
        swap(i, i - 1); i--
    }
}

function process(    i) {
    for (i = 1; i <= NR; i++)
        if (tags[i] == "forall") rise(i)
}

function dump(    i) { # print the array
    for (i = 1; i <= NR; i++)
        print lines[i]
}

END {
    process()
    dump()
}
```

An example of input file

```
$ cat r.txt
goal identifier statement  
let statement 1  
let statement 2  
forall statement A  
other statements

goal identifier statement  
let statement 1  
let statement 2  
forall statement B
other statements
```

Usage:

```
$ awk -f r.awk r.txt
goal identifier statement  
forall statement A  
let statement 1  
let statement 2  
other statements

goal identifier statement  
forall statement B
let statement 1  
let statement 2  
other statements
```

Answer (score 0):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. For anything else you should use awk for every desirable attribute of software (clarity, simplicity, portability, etc.:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{if (/forall/) {f=FNR; v=$0} next} FNR!=f; /goal/{print v} ' file file
goal identifier statement
forall statement
let statement 1
let statement 2
other statements
```

Comment: Would be helpful with an explanation of each awk item...

Comment: @not2qubit no, it's all trivial and obvious after a quick read of the awk manual.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r '/goal/{                 # if match "goal" line
    :X                          # this is a lable for branch command
    N                           # append next line
    /forall[^\n]*$/{            # if match "forall" line move to "goal" line below
        s#^([^\n]*)(.*)(\n[^\n]*)$#\1\3\2# 
        b                       # after move finished branch to end
    } 
    bX                          # branch to :X for appending next line
}' file
goal identifier statement  
forall statement  
let statement 1  
let statement 2  
other statements
```

Comment: Please consider adding a brief explanation of *how* the above solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

A less terrible way using vim to find a line in $FILENAME using regex $REGEX_EXPRESSION and move that line to $LINE_NUMBER:

```
vim -c "g:$REGEX_EXPRESSION:m$LINE_NUMBER" -cwq "$FILENAME"
```

explanation: `-c` is command in vim, so it goes to the first line that matches that regex and then moves it to the line number specified, and then does the command `wq` (or write and quit).